# Vagrant base box for Ubuntu with Gnome

Tags: ubuntu, vagrant, virtualbox, gnome

I have to set up an Ubuntu 16.04 Gnome development VM on Windows 10 using Vagrant and VirtualBox.

I've googled and checked the available Vagrant boxes on the [Vagrant site](https://app.vagrantup.com/boxes/search?provider=virtualbox&q=ubuntu+gnome&sort=downloads&utf8=%E2%9C%93), but the most recent box I found was over 2 years old and used Ubuntu 15.04.

Am I looking in the wrong places or is there really nothing newer available?

Answer (score 0):

Completely forgot about the bento boxes. There's an Ubuntu 17.10 box available which uses Gnome by default: https://app.vagrantup.com/bento/boxes/ubuntu-17.10

Comment: I tried this box, but didn't get gnome working. I enabled the gui option with   config.vm.provider "virtualbox" do |vb|
    vb.gui = true